# Extract part of a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I extract a part of a sentence like this :

```
var sentence = "This is my sentence. I want to extract a part of it (in javascript !)";
var subSentence1 = "nt t";
var subSentence2 = "t (in javasc";

var result1 = f(sentence,subSentence1);
var result2 = f(sentence,subSentence2);
```

I'd like to have :

> result1 = "want to"

and

> result2 = "it (in javascript"

Thanks

Comment: We need more detail to be able to provide answers. what do the `subSentence` variables have to do with this processing? also, what have you tried? why did it fail?

Comment: I need this processing for autocompletion purpose.
I'm not familiar with regex expressions, so I have some difficulties to find the good regex

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your `subSentence` variables so `(` should be `\(` which means `t (in javasc` should be `t \(in javasc`.

Use a string replace for all your string variables used in the regex.

```
var subSentence1 = subSentence1.substring('(', '\(');
```

The regex that will give the desired results are these.

```
var patt = new RegExp("[^\s]*nt t.*?(?=\s)")
var patt = new RegExp("[^\s]*t \(in javasc.*?(?=\s)")
```

So you put your subSentence variable in between `[^\s]*` and `.*?(?=\s)`.

Construct a regex string like

```
var patt = new RegExp("[^\s]*" + subSentence + ".*?(?=\s)")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to regular expressions I suggest you to take a look at this must-have [reference](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/). I personally always refer to it after I haven't used regex and have forgotten the syntax.